# How can i fetch another table data in different table column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Firstly i have given all three table structure.

**actions table:**
[image: actionsTable]

**roles table:**
[image: rolesTable]

**permissions table:**
[image]

Here how can i get `action_id` in `permissions` table from `actions` table?
and how can i get `role_id` in `permissions` table from `roles` table? Please tell me the easy way to do , i am beginner in Laravel.

**Action Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Action extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = "actions";
    //public $fillable = []


    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Action');
    }    
    public function permission(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Action');
    }
}
```

**Permission Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Permission extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table ="permissions";

    public function actionGet(){
        return $this->hasOne('App/Permission');
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean Insert action_id data from action_table to permission table ??

Comment: Yes when i have `id` in `action` table then i want to insert data in `action_id` of `permission` table.

Comment: "Please tell me the easy way to do" - Seriously, if you want to learn, stop looking for the easy way.

Comment: If i want to learn firstly in complex way then i think i can be failed thats why i want to learn first easy way then i go through complex way.Hope you understand my word. @DanWhite

Comment: @chonchol can you please explain where do you need this. I mean where exactly do get into a situation that you want to add an entry to permissions table without having the record in actions table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do this work.I am using for this **[Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)** to insert `actions` table `id` in `permissions` table `action_id` column.

For this, in **RoleController:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $role = [];
    $role['role'] = $request->input('role');

   $data= Role::create($role);
   $id= $data->id;
   DB::table('permissions')->insert([
    'role_id' => $id
    ]);
    return redirect(route('allRole'));
}
```

And **ActionController:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $action= [];
    $action['action'] = $request->input('action');

   $data= Action::create($action);
   $id= $data->id;
   DB::table('permissions')->insert([
    'action_id' => $id
    ]);
    return redirect(route('allAction'));
}
```

Before do this add `use DB;` in your header of each controller.

Hope this will help for someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
update permission_table a join action_table b on a.id = b.id join roles_table c
on a.id = c.id
set a.action_id = b.id,
a.role_id = c.id;
```

This will update action_id in permission table with id from action table 
also, role_id in permission table with id from role table.
I assume this is what you want.

Comment: Ok i am trying and let you know what happened.Will i do it in which model? and how can i call this in controller?

Comment: Its's a mysql query to update role_id and action_id in permission table.

As you are using phpMyadmin, there should be a tab with SQL .
open it and run this query

Comment: I this is sql query but this is just show the result at once.But i want when i have `id` in `action` table then i have also fill up `action_id` in `permissions` table and also keep that data in `action_id` column.

Comment: create trigger on action_table and role_table 
to insert or update into permission_table.

Check below link
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html